# How to find CDI beans with a custom annotation with parameters?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, weld

I have a Wildfly 10 application in which I have created a custom @Qualifer annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,TYPE})
@Qualifier
public @interface DbType {
    /**
     * If this DbType is part of the initialization process for an existing DB
     */
    boolean init() default false;
}
```

I then have a couple of producer methods:

```
@Produces
@DbType
public MyBean createBean1(){
  return new MyBean();
}

@Produces
@DbType(init=true)
public MyBean createBean2(){
  return new MyBean(true);
}
```

In my code, I want to programatically retrieve all beans with the given annotation, but not sure how.

```
    Instance<MyBean> configs = CDI.current().select(MyBean.class, new AnnotationLiteral<DbType >() {});
```

will return both beans.

How can I specify in my CDI.current().select() that I only want beans with the qualifer `@MyType(init=true)`?

Comment: Why didn't you just Instance<MyBean> by the Qualifier: @DbType(init=true)? What did I not understand here?

Comment: @aschoerk You cannot use CDI.current.select() with an annotation with parameters.  You need to use `AnnotationLiteral`, but cannot do it with an anonymous class inline.  See the accepted answer from Slaw below which solves the issue.

Comment: I thought you only wanted the Beans with Qualifier @MyType()... so if you annotate Instance<MyBean> configs this way, there should not be any other beans than those you are interested in. So you wont need to call select, you can just annotate using @Inject @MyType(init=true) Instance<MyBean> configs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need create a class that extends [`AnnotationLiteral`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral.html) and implements your annotation. An example is given by the documentation of `AnnotationLiteral`:

> Supports inline instantiation of annotation type instances.
>
> An instance of an annotation type may be obtained by subclassing AnnotationLiteral.
>
> ```
> public abstract class PayByQualifier extends AnnotationLiteral<PayBy> implements PayBy {
> }
>
> PayBy payByCheque = new PayByQualifier() {
>     public PaymentMethod value() {
>         return CHEQUE;
>     }
> };
> ```

In your case, it might look something like:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,TYPE})
@Qualifier
public @interface DbType {
    /**
     * If this DbType is part of the initialization process for an existing DB
     */
    boolean init() default false;

    class Literal extends AnnotationLiteral<DbType> implements DbType {

        public static Literal INIT = new Literal(true);
        public static Literal NO_INIT = new Literal(false);

        private final boolean init;

        private Literal(boolean init) {
            this.init = init;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean init() {
            return init;
        }

    }

}
```

And then use it:

```
Instance<MyBean> configs = CDI.current().select(MyBean.class, DbType.Literal.INIT);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  Really helped.  Of course, that's not a far cry from just creating 2 different `@Qualifer` classes in the first place.  Am just a little surprised there isn't an easier way to do this.

Comment: It's the cost of using the annotations "inline". Even if you had two different `@Qualifier` annotations you'd still have to create the "literal" classes, except now you'd have two of them. The problem "literal annotations" solve is that you can't instantiate an annotation normally. In order to instantiate the annotation we need a class that implements the annotation. Luckily the API provides `AnnotationLiteral` which, if you look at the implementation, does quite a lot of work for us.